# locate conditional column value based on row max

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe, row

This is a simple version of a much larger `df_data` 1000 x 150

```
Date            A   B   C   D        A'  B' C'  D'
31/01/2017      47  15  45  40       10  7  12   8
28/02/2017      22  34  28  13        3  2  26   4
31/03/2017      25  12  13  47        1  5   6  59
```

Basic problem is need row sort of columns A,B,C,D and use max/min criteria to locate corresponding row values in columns A',B',C',D'

Need following pls.

(1) Find the n highest values and n lowest values for each date (row).
Let's assume n=2 here.
(2) Conditional on min/max value from (1) use relevant column header to find the corresponding value in the same row for a different column from A',B,C',D'
(in the same df or different df with exact same index of dates)

Assume there is a 1-1 mapping between A,B,C,D and A',B',C',D')

Desired result:

```
31/01/2017: max1 = 10, max2 =12 ; min1 = 7, min2 = 8
28/02/2017: max1 =  2, max2 =26 ; min1 = 4, min2 = 3
31/03/2017: max1 = 59, max2 = 1 ; min1 = 5, min2 = 6
```

I can find the max for e.g using

```
df_data [["A","B","C","D"]].apply(lambda row: np.max(row),axis=1)
```

But how do I use `iloc` function within `.apply` or some other way to find the col header(index) of that max value? (I tried `.argsort` in `numpy` array but couldn't get anywhere)

Also how do I find the top `n` and bottom `n` values in each row (where `n > 1`) - using `rank` or `sort`? I tried following to sort the rows (descending)

```
df_data.values.sort
df_data = df_data.iloc[:,::-1]
```

This seems to work but my end goal is to find the values in columns A',B',C',D'

Sorry if a bit long.

Answer (score 0):

I used [Numpy Fancy Indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html#indexing-multi-dimensional-arrays).

The first step is determining the index of the maximum element in the `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` columns.  [`np.argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) would work, but you mention that you want to find the smallest, second largest, second smallest etc. so use [`np.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html).

```
>>> idxs = df['A B C D'.split()].apply(np.argsort, axis=1).values
```

In your example `idxs` is:

```
array([[1, 3, 2, 0],
       [3, 0, 2, 1],
       [1, 2, 0, 3]], dtype=int64)
```

The first column of `idxs` is the index of the smallest element in the `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` columns by row.  That is, `df.iloc[0, 1]` is 15, the smallest element in the first row.  `df.iloc[1, 3]` is 13, the smallest element in the second row. etc.  The second column of `idxs` is the index of the second smallest.  The last column of `idxs` is the index of the largest element.

We use this to Numpy Fancy Indexing into the `A'`, `B'`, `C'`, `D'` columns.  To do this we use two arrays to subscript the two dimensional array.  The first array is the row index, the second array is the desired column in each row.

```
>>> df[["A'", "B'", "C'", "D'"]].values[np.arange(nrow), idxs[:, -1]]
```

Since we are using the last column of `idxs` we are selecting the index of the largest item in columns `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` from the columns `A'`, `B'`, `C'`, `D'`.  So the result is

```
array(['10', '2', '59'], dtype=object)
```

as desired.

To select the elements corresponding to the smallest use

```
>>> df[["A'", "B'", "C'", "D'"]].values[np.arange(nrow), idxs[:, 0]]
array(['7', '4', '5'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: thanks meta4. 2 questions please - array(['10', '2', '59'], dtype=object) above is a one-dim array. I need this array for all the rows in my df. i tried for i in range(-bot_n,top_n):
    idxs2 = df2.values[np.arange(nrow), idxs[:, i]]
how do I populate idxs2 (2D) to contain all the arrays for all rows? or is it easier to write to a df? sorry I am new to np arrays and df

Comment: 2nd question: i have created 2 dfs - one for A B C D ,,,and other for A' B' C' D'...as i have a lot of columns i tried to remove the .split and do below:           
    idxs = df.apply(np.argsort, axis=1)                    
    idxs2 = df2.values[np.arange(nrow), idxs[:, i]]1).values                                              is there a better way? txs

Comment: I'm not sure I can answer all your questions here.  I suggest looking at the documentation for [np.argsort](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html).  The contents of the `idxs` array is all the information you need to find the smallest, largest, second-smallest, second-largest, etc. element of A B C D etc.  It doesn't matter if A' B' C' D' are in the same DataFrame or a different data frame.

Comment: thanks. i got it to work.  The rows in A' B' C' D' I wanted mapped to A B C D with an offset - in code below I used "lag" for the offset. not sure if there is a simple function to do the same i did with brute force?                                       for i in range(lag,nrow):
        for j in range (ncol):
            c= (idxs[i-lag,j])
            df_rankRet.iloc[i-lag,j]=df_ret.iloc[i,c]